# Distance magnitude change between an orbited object and a planet in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, orbital-mechanics

I'am having a very hard time since i can't understand the problem :

I am trying to make an object move on a circular orbit around a planet using a formula found on wikipedia, any ways here is my code :

```
public void circularOrbit(Collider2D col,float planetMass){

    mPlanet = planetMass;
    dist = new Vector2 (col.gameObject.transform.position.x - gameObject.transform.position.x, col.gameObject.transform.position.y - gameObject.transform.position.y);
    r = dist.magnitude;
    print (r);
    tdist = new Vector2 (-dist.y, dist.x).normalized; // 2D vector prependicular to the dist vector .
    float speed =  Mathf.Sqrt ( G*mPlanet / r)  ; // Calculate the velocity .
    print (speed);
    rigidbody2D.velocity = tdist * speed; 


}
```

The 2D Collider `col` is the collider of the planet orbit, when my object hit this collider it start moving on a circular way according to the calculations that i've made .

Everything goes inside a fixed update with some conditions (not really related to this topic ) , the problem that i'am facing is that my distance magnitude keep changing everyframe, where i need it to stay the same !

This cause problem since the speed will change and for other scripts i need it fixed .

Here are some values of `r` the distance magnitude :

> 4.602833
>
> 4.602901
>
> 4.603098

The changing is very small, but it affect my gameplay too much .

So please explain why it's hapenning ?

Thank's .

Comment: "So please explain why it's hapenning ?" - There are lot of floating point calculations going on your code and the floating point precision is the devil here I think. Another thing maybe the impact of colliding that cause your gameobjects' distance is changing very slightly. "Workaround"- Maybe Mathf.Round you can use to restrict the floating point decimal value. "Solution maybe"- When colliding with collider of the planet orbit, check that only once, get the value of r and do the orbiting separately. No need to check the distance every frame or FixedUpdate() etc. as math functions are heavy.

Comment: Well actually I'am trying to do that but, there is another problem : The object get in orbit a small moment, and then he get out of orbit . Also my logic is that when the object hit the planet collider isOrbit become true, and then in the FixedUpdate i check for this bool variable and if it's true, I call this function , I did all dist and r  calculations on OnTriggerEnter2D, those variable are global one so they are used directly by the circularOrbit function .

Comment: Physics engines aren't fully deterministic and have limited precision. How does a variation of ~0.0003 units break your game? You could take control of the object directly, you could tweak physics settings, or you could re-work your design a bit to accommodate this variation.

Answer (score 0):

The physics engine performs its updates on the fixed updates. Between these updates, gravity is not acting on the object. So, it moves in a straight line segment that starts out tangent to the circle you want, but at the end of the fixed update period, the distance has increased slightly since the line segment is not the same as the circle. The result is that you might see errors much larger than roundoff errors.

This error is linear. If you have twice as many updates, or decrease the speed and force of gravity by a factor of two, the errors on each step will shrink by about a factor of four, but since you have twice as many updates per orbit, the extra distance per orbit would decrease by a factor of two.

If you had a complicated simulation with objects moving in ellipses and multiple significant sources of gravity, then I would suggest using a method like [leapfrog integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration), which conserves energy, or a high order Runge-Kutta method, which is typically so accurate that you won't notice the errors. However, you are already imposing a circular orbit instead of letting the physics engine calculate the orbit. So, just override the physics engine's calculations, and force the object to be in the place along the orbit you know it should be. One way to do this is to rotate the old displacement from the planet's center by an angle which is (Time.deltaTime/period) * 2pi radians. This is not perfect because there are some roundoff errors that may accumulate. Another possibility is to keep track of the original location and the original time, and calculate the angle changed based on the difference between the current time and the original time.

Another method that should work is to remember what the radius is supposed to be, and renormalize the displacement from the planet's center to have a magnitude equal to the remembered radius.

Comment: Well, Thank you for your answer, I'am only a high school student so my math/physics are limited fo now, I see your last solution very logical, since i can get the radius of each orbit, here my full code with this solution :  http://pastebin.com/0GCDEL7F  , The code is very easy to understand, but now i have another problem, which is very weird : My object is moving out of the orbit while the `r` stay the same, the same goes for the velocity magnitude and speed . Here is a gif explaining my current problem : http://giphy.com/gifs/3oEdv73oLD3BtcP5M4 .

Comment: Yes, this answer explained why you are seeing the object spiral out and how you can fix that. I warned about that in a comment after my answer to the last question.